# Return statement not working with User defined functions in Arangodb? How to write an AQl query inside a function?

Tags: arangodb

```
require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register(
    "MYFUNCTIONS::VERTEX::INDEGREE", 
    function(vertex,edge, node) {
        "use strict"; 
        AQL_Query(
            (return( "for t in Transaction  collect vertex_count=t._from with into n return x"))
        )
    }
);
```

throws the following exception

```
JavaScript exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'
!require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register("MYFUNCTIONS::VERTEX::INDEGREE", function(vertex,edge, node) {"use strict"; AQL_Query((return( "for t in Transaction  collect vertex_count=t._from with into n return x")))});
!                                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^
stacktrace: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `aql` template string handler to assamble the query, something like this should get you started:

```js
require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register(
    "MYFUNCTIONS::VERTEX::INDEGREE", 
    function(vertex,edge, node) {
        "use strict";
        let db = require('@arangodb').db;
        let aql = require('@arangodb').aql;
        
        let query = aql`
            for t in Transaction  
              collect vertex_count=t._from with into n 
              return n
        `;
        return db._query(query).toArray();
    }
);
```

Comment: Also how to call a function in the Arangoshell?

Comment: In AQL-statements; you register functions for use in aql statements...; `db._query(aql\`return MYFUNCTIONS::VERTEX::INDEGREE()\`);`.  Maybe a foxx-service is what you really want to develop? (though a registered function can be a nice stepping stone).

Comment: To call user functions from user functions see this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366753/arangodb-can-i-call-a-user-function-from-a-user-function